# Cocos2d problem/question

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am making a game in Cocos2d. I want enemies to spawn on the right and left sides of the screen, and move to a random point on the screen, then repeat. Despite my efforts, I cannot figure it out. This should be relatively easy to answer, it should look like something out of one of Ray Wenderlich's tutorials. Some code would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code from ray Wanderlich tutorial..

```
[self schedule:@selector(addTarget) interval:2.0];

-(void)addTarget {

  CCSprite *target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Target.jpg"  
    rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 27, 40)]; //Creating Sprite and setting rect

  // Determine where to spawn the target along the Y axis
  CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]; //Get the screensize
  int minY = target.contentSize.height/2;
  int maxY = winSize.height - target.contentSize.height/2;
  int rangeY = maxY - minY;
  int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

  // Create the target slightly off-screen along the right edge,
  // and along a random position along the Y axis as calculated above
  target.position = ccp(winSize.width + (target.contentSize.width/2), actualY);
  [self addChild:target];

  // Determine speed of the target
  int minDuration = 2.0;
  int maxDuration = 4.0;
  int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
  int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

  // Create the actions
  id actionMove = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:actualDuration 
    position:ccp(-target.contentSize.width/2, actualY)];
  id actionMoveDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self 
    selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)];
  [target runAction:[CCSequence actions:actionMove, actionMoveDone, nil]];

}
```

minY-->position at the bottom of the screen
maxY--->position at the top of the screen.
rangeY ---> the height of the screen.
actualY--->calculate the random point between bottom of the screen and top of the screen.

target.position --> setting random position for the sprite to move.

actualDuration --> getting random duration.so that the sprite moves in various time delay.

actionMove --> creating Move action.
actionMoveDone ---> After completing move action,calling spriteMoveFinished to remove sprites.